# How read this log?

Tags: logging, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

The following log is generated from ELB of AWS (application ELB) .

Can you help to read this log

```
http 2019-07-26T00:02:23.641877Z app/api-sharkcloud/045932bf06ccdceb 216.218.206.69:53414 - -1 -1 -1 301 - 40 350 "GET http://13.235.126.213:8080/ HTTP/1.1" "-" - - - "Root=1-5d3a430f-7d4e1c7d85c82fc730297718" "-" "-" 0 2019-07-26T00:02:23.641000Z "redirect" "https://13.235.126.213:443/" "-"
```

Could you let me know what does `- -1 -1 -1 301 - 40 350 "GET`  mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it . Following document will help to read this log .

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html

if any one in future need help reagardig reading elb log file can use this doc.